# What's the most suitable sound/audio framework for iPhone OpenGL-ES games?

Tags: iphone, frameworks, audio

I'm writing a game for iPhone/iPod.

My engine is using OpenGL-ES, and this means game requires some performance.
(realtime games, not a static board-game like games.)

I looked at basic sound framework in iPhone, there're several frameworks,(Core Audio, Audio Toolbox, OpenAL...) but I cannot determine differences of them in detail.

I think OpenAL will gain best performance, but it's just a guess with no clue. And iPhone/iPod is a music player hardware, I cannot know in-depth features of iPhone/iPod.

I'm new to all of those framework, so I have to study one of them. And now I'm choosing one.

The features required for me is:

- Delay-less playback. Sound effect should be a realtime feedback.
- Streamed long music playback with very small memory footprint.
- Volume control per playback of sound effect.
- Mixing. Multiple difference sound effect can be played at same time. (around 4 or more)
- Other feature required for games.
- Hardware acceleration (if exists)
- Realtime filtering effect (reverb, echo, 3D, ...) if possible.
- ...

Can you recommend a framework for my game? And some explanation about each framework also will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do everything you want with **OpenAL**. It's what I'd recommend for a game.

Plus, it's the only framework for 3D positional audio which often goes hand-in-hand with a 3D game.

Answer (score 1):

OpenAL, Core Audio, AudioToolbox etc. are wrappers around the same things: namely, Apple’s own audio processing features. OpenAL is just a different interface but has the same performance as Core Audio, as it sends commands to the same things.

There are several other “audio engines” out there that are just wrappers.

At risk of tooting my own horn, Superpowered is the only audio SDK that outperforms Apple’s Core Audio on mobile devices. It’s specifically designed to outperform every single one of those, with lower memory footprint, CPU load and battery usage. For example, the Superpowered reverb is 5x faster than Apple’s.  See http://superpowered.com/reverb/